# how to get information within <meta name...> tag in html using htmlParse and xpathSApply

Tags: html, xml, r

I have a bunch of webpages and I want to extract their publishing dates. 
For some webpages, the dates are in the "abbr" tag (like: abbr class=\"published\" title=\"2012-03-14T07:13:39+00:00\">2012-03-14,  7:13"), and I was able to get the dates using: 
doc=htmlParse(theURL,asText=T)
xpathSApply(doc,"//abbr",xmlValue)

But for other webpages, the dates are in the "mega" tags, for example:
meta name=\"created\" content=\"2011-12-29T11:49:23+00:00\"
meta name=\"OriginalPublicationDate\" content=\"2012/11/14 10:56:58\"

I tried xpathSApply(doc, "//meta",xmlValue), but it didn't work.

So, what pattern should I use instead of "//meta"?

Thank you!

Comment: In what way didn't it work? What happened?

Comment: @jlhoward There are altogether 8 meta tags in the page and I was interested in one of them. The xpathSApply function gave me 8 ""s (NAs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this page as an example:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342501/"
doc <- htmlParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
names   <- doc["//meta/@name"]
content <- doc["//meta/@content"]
cbind(names,content)
#      names            content                                                                                                           
# [1,] "twitter:card"   "summary"                                                                                                         
# [2,] "twitter:domain" "stackoverflow.com"                                                                                               
# [3,] "og:type"        "website"                                                                                                         
# [4,] "og:image"       "http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=fde65a5a78c6"                                  
# [5,] "og:title"       "how to get information within <meta name...> tag in html using htmlParse and xpathSApply"                        
# [6,] "og:description" "I have a bunch of webpages and I want to extract their publishing dates. \nFor some webpages, the da" [truncated]
# [7,] "og:url"         "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342501/how-to-get-information-within-meta-name-tag-in-html-usi" [truncated]
```

The problem with

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//meta",xmlValue)
```

is that `xmlValue(...)` returns the *element* content (e.g, the text part of an element). `<meta>` tags have no text.