# Getting the right meta data in XML file using R - unequal length of content and properties?

Tags: html, xml, r, metadata

I am using R to get meta data from a website, e.g. from this website: http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/03/redphone-and-textsecure-combine-to-form-signal-a-single-app-for-private-calls-and-texts/

The meta data looks like the following:

```
    <title>[Deal Alert] Best Buy Is Offering A Refurbished Kwikset Kevo Bluetooth Door Lock For $130 ($70 Off) Today Only</title>
<meta name="description" content="If you&#039;ve been drooling over Kwikset&#039;s Bluetooth-powered, Android-compatible power door locks, but you&#039;ve been wary of the high entry price, today is the d... by Michael Crider in Accessories, Deals, News"/>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/04/deal-alert-best-buy-is-offering-a-refurbished-kwikset-kevo-bluetooth-door-lock-for-130-70-off-today-only/"/>
<link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/103876278794381402383"/>
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="[Deal Alert] Best Buy Is Offering A Refurbished Kwikset Kevo Bluetooth Door Lock For $130 ($70 Off) Today Only"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="If you&#039;ve been drooling over Kwikset&#039;s Bluetooth-powered, Android-compatible power door locks, but you&#039;ve been wary of the high entry price, today is the d... by Michael Crider in Accessories, Deals, News"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/11/04/deal-alert-best-buy-is-offering-a-refurbished-kwikset-kevo-bluetooth-door-lock-for-130-70-off-today-only/"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Android Police - Android News, Apps, Games, Phones, Tablets"/>
<meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/AndroidPolice"/>
<meta property="article:tag" content="Best Buy,bluetooth,deal alert,kevo,Kwikset,Kwikset Kevo,one day only,refurbished"/>
<meta property="article:section" content="Accessories"/>
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2015-11-04T10:48:00-08:00"/>
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2015-11-04T10:48:18-08:00"/>
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2015-11-04T10:48:18-08:00"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nexus2cee_kevo_thumb.png"/>
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"/>
<meta name="twitter:description" content="If you&#039;ve been drooling over Kwikset&#039;s Bluetooth-powered, Android-compatible power door locks, but you&#039;ve been wary of the high entry price, today is the d... by Michael Crider in Accessories, Deals, News"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="[Deal Alert] Best Buy Is Offering A Refurbished Kwikset Kevo Bluetooth Door Lock For $130 ($70 Off) Today Only"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@AndroidPolice"/>
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="Android Police - Android News, Apps, Games, Phones, Tablets"/>
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/nexus2cee_kevo_thumb.png"/>
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@michaelcrider"/>
```

At the moment, I am trying to get access to the "Accessories" section in

```
<meta property="article:section" content="Accessories"/>
```

I am using an approach that I found here: [how to get information within <meta name...> tag in html using htmlParse and xpathSApply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342501/how-to-get-information-within-meta-name-tag-in-html-using-htmlparse-and-xpa) (see the answer by jlhoward)

Here is my code:

```
tmp <- readLines(str_c("androidpolice/", 1, ".html"))
tmp <- str_c(tmp, collapse = "")
tmp <- htmlParse(tmp)

content = tmp["//meta/@content"]
property = tmp["//meta/@property"]

length(content)
# 26
length(property)
# 14
```

However, my problem is that the length of the meta files content and meta files properties are not equal, hence I cannot combine them and extract the one content I need.

I have no idea how to access the "Accessories" data. Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to bother you with this, but in development process, it is easier not to erase and rewrite on the same object. Keeping all the step by step result allow you to debug more easily. If you have any idea, call them tmp.1, tmp.2, etc..

Comment: I see. That's just how our teacher does it in his example code. But yes, I agree, it is not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you could find all the properties of xpath:
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp

with

```
content = tmp["//meta/@content"]
```

you extract all the node meta with the attribute content
with

```
property = tmp["//meta/@property"]
```

you extract all the node meta with the property content

Try this to access the node with property equal to article:session:

```
property = tmp["//meta/@property = 'article:section'"]
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do I access content of the property "article:section". In other words, how do I get access to the "Accessory" string? Sorry, I am very new to web and R.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround solution. It's not elegant, but it seems to work for now:

```
# meta data: section
content = tmp["//meta/@content"]

# get all meta data, but mark everything except 'property' as NULL
properties = xpathSApply(tmp, "//meta", xmlGetAttr, "property")

# find the meta data containing the 'section' property
sectionIndex = 0;
dateIndex = 0;
for (j in 1:length(properties))
{
  if (grepl("article:section",properties[j]) == TRUE)
    sectionIndex = j;

  if (grepl("article:published_time",properties[j]) == TRUE)
    dateIndex = j;
}

# set the section and publication date
section = content[sectionIndex];
date = content[dateIndex];
```